# Can't run react native app in xcode simulator!

Tags: ios, terminal, xcode

newbie to react-native, was following this official docs for creating ios app: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

**My System config** :

[image: my system config]

Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

---

Ran this below commands to create the app & to run it in ios simulator (as mentioned in docs) ...

1] react-native init AwesomeProject

2] cd AwesomeProject

3] react-native run-ios

---

But got below error after like 10 mins in terminal...

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Volumes/Jupiter/Projects/AwesomeProject/ios/build/AwesomeProject
....

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Volumes/Jupiter/Projects/AwesomeProject/ios/build/AwesomeProject/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLinkingManager.o /Volumes/Jupiter/Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Comment: Those logs tell us very little, Just do as it says " To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace."